# OAuth2 Google Api java/eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-admin-sdk, google-oauth-java-client

I'm looking at [this example]https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/quickstart-java).

But I don't want to use that url copy/paste version to auth so I've read that I should use serviceaccount.

I downloaded the p12 key and placed it in my source folder. 
And I'm rebuilding the Google Example with some code I found on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882349/error-while-using-google-apps-admin-directory-api-and-drive-api-at-the-same-tim)

So here's how far I get:

```
public class DirectoryCommandLine {

    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
  JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

    // Build service account credential.
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
        .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
        .setServiceAccountId("......82p@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
        .setServiceAccountScopes(DirectoryScopes.all())
       .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new java.io.File("eclipsejava-d6675et3ab71.p12"))
        .build();


    // Create a new authorized API client
    Directory service = new Directory.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
        .setApplicationName("DirectoryCommandLine")
        .build();

    List<User> allUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
    Directory.Users.List request = service.users().list().setCustomer("my_customer");

    // Get all users
    do {
      try {
        Users currentPage = request.execute();
        allUsers.addAll(currentPage.getUsers());
        request.setPageToken(currentPage.getNextPageToken());
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
        request.setPageToken(null);
      }
    } while (request.getPageToken() != null &&
             request.getPageToken().length() > 0 );

    // Print all users
    for (User currentUser : allUsers) {
      System.out.println(currentUser.getPrimaryEmail());
    }
  }
}
```

If I run this I get this error:

```
Error: Main method not found in class DirectoryCommandLine, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
```

I guess i need to add

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
```

Infront/Before:

```
  HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
  JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
```

But then it all gets a mess:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Google APIs but Java class structure. Considering you are a beginner in Java you should start with more simple exercises.

Oracle and Internet provide a lot of documentation about Java. You can start looking at these links for example :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html

Comment: Hi Cimbalii, thank you for taking your time and replying to my question. There are different types of learning, im the kind of person who DO things to learn, i just need this to work, then i can build more and extend what i need to build. If there is any one that could help me fix this, it's probably a no brainer.